# How to use external file as a source of variables for Bash script file?

Tags: bash, file, variables, external

I am new to Bash scripting and I need help with something.

The file **bbb.txt** contains many *IPv4 and IPv6 addresses*, like this:

```
10.0.2.15    fe80...
192.168.1.1   fe80...
```

The file **aaa.txt** has many *iptables commands*.

I want my script to find all IPv4 addresses in `aaa.txt` and check if they can be found in `bbb.txt`, when matched - IPv4 in aaa.txt is replaced with IPv6 from bbb.txt. Is it doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save this to a file e.g. `script.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A A
while read -ra __; do
    A[${__[0]}]=${__[1]}
done < "$2"
while read -r __; do
    for I in "${!A[@]}"; do
        [[ $__ == *"$I"* ]] && {
            V=${A[$I}
            __=${__//"$I"/"$V"}
        }
    done
    echo "$__"
done < "$1"
```

Then run `bash script.sh aaa.txt bbb.txt`.

To get the output run it as something like `bash script.sh aaa.txt bbb.txt > out.txt`

I prefer to use Bash this time since you have to quote non-literals in Awk.

Another solution through Ruby:

```
ruby -e 'f = File.open(ARGV[0]).read; File.open(ARGV[1]).readlines.map{|l| l.split}.each{|a| f.gsub!(a[0], a[1])}; puts f' aaa.txt bbb.txt
```

Another way to modify file directly:

```
#!/bin/bash
A=$(<"$1")
while read -ra B; do
    A=${A//"${B[0]}"/"${B[1]}"}
done < "$2"
echo "$A" > "$1"
```

Run as `bash script.sh aaa.txt bbb.txt`.

Another through Ruby:

```
ruby -e 'x = File.read(ARGV[0]); File.open(ARGV[1]).readlines.map{|l| l.split}.each{|a| x.gsub!(a[0], a[1])}; File.write(ARGV[0], x)' aaa.txt bbb.txt
```

Comment: Nice replies, thanks. Can you tell me why the file aaa.txt is not changed? In other words: effects are not saved, I want script.sh to change aaa.txt after finding a match in bbb.txt.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better off using `perl` for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file1 = 'aaa.txt';
my $file2 = 'bbb.txt';

open my $if1,'<',$file1 or die "$file1: $!\n";
open my $if2,'<',$file2 or die "$file2: $!\n";

my %ip_dictionary;
while(<$if2>){
    my ($ipv4,$ipv6)=split;
    $ip_dictionary{$ipv4}=$ipv6;
}
close $if2;

my $slurp = do { local $/; <$if1>};
close $if1;

$slurp=~ s!((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})!exists $ip_dictionary{$1} and is_valid_ip($1) ? $ip_dictionary{$1} : $1!eg;

open my $of,'>',$file1;
print $of $slurp;

sub is_valid_ip{
    my $ip=shift//return 0;
    for(split /\./,$ip){
        return 0 if $_ > 255;
    }
    1
}
```